# How to unite two columns of date + time for datediff - Oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two **int** columns:
thedate - for example 20210512
thetime - for example 142342

So, i need to unite them to one column to check if the time difference is lower the 5.

I tried this:

TO_DATE(sysdate)  -  TO_DATE(thedate, 'YYYY-MM-DD')  < 5

But it only for the date not for the time so i will be glad to know how to unite the two int columns + and convert it to date type for time difference.

Comment: Don't use `TO_DATE` on a date value like `SYSDATE`; just use `SYSDATE` directly.

Comment: If you are stuck with the data design, then so be it. But please, please, please understand that this design is _seriously_ flawed.  Oracle provides both DATE and TIMESTAMP data types, and they both include both date and time. DATE keeps time down to the second, and TIMESTAMP keeps time down to the nano-second, as well has having a couple of variants for handling time zone.  Dates/times should be kept in these data types.  If you had the proper data types, your problem would be trivial.

Answer (score 1):

You want to convert to a timestamp, not a date.  So:

```
select to_timestamp(cast(20210512 * 1000000 + 142342 as varchar2(255)), 'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS')
from dual;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=611f54649bb8f745b20d36304e34f516) is a db<>fiddle showing that this works.

Or in a `where` clause:

```
to_timestamp(cast(thedate * 1000000 + thetime as varchar2(255)), 'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS') > sysdate - interval '5' day
```

(or whatever you mean by "5").

Note:  You may want to add a computed column to the table that has the full timestamp:

```
alter table t add column timestamp generated always as
    ( to_timestamp(cast(thedate * 10000 + thetime as varchar2(255)), 'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS') );
```

Comment: thank you but i got this error:  "hour must be between 0 and 23"

Comment: What is the reason that you say you need to use `TIMESTAMP` rather than `DATE`?

Comment: @EfraimEfiGavrieli . . . **You** changed the question -- 1423 is not 142342.  I updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   table_name
WHERE  TO_DATE( thedate * 1000000 + thetime, 'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS' ) > SYSDATE - 5;
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name ( thedate INT, thetime INT );
INSERT INTO TABLE_NAME ( thedate, thetime ) VALUES (
  TO_NUMBER( TO_CHAR( SYSDATE, 'YYYYMMDD' ) ),
  TO_NUMBER( TO_CHAR( SYSDATE, 'HH24MISS' ) )
);
INSERT INTO TABLE_NAME ( thedate, thetime ) VALUES (
  TO_NUMBER( TO_CHAR( SYSDATE - INTERVAL '4 23' DAY TO HOUR, 'YYYYMMDD' ) ),
  TO_NUMBER( TO_CHAR( SYSDATE - INTERVAL '4 23' DAY TO HOUR, 'HH24MISS' ) )
);
INSERT INTO TABLE_NAME ( thedate, thetime ) VALUES (
  TO_NUMBER( TO_CHAR( SYSDATE - INTERVAL '5 1' DAY TO HOUR, 'YYYYMMDD' ) ),
  TO_NUMBER( TO_CHAR( SYSDATE - INTERVAL '5 1' DAY TO HOUR, 'HH24MISS' ) )
);
```

Outputs:

> | THEDATE | THETIME |
> | --- | --- |
> | 20210512 | 131832 |
> | 20210507 | 141832 |

Or, if you want to use indexes on the `thedate` and `thetime` columns (the query above would not use indexes on `thedate` and `thetime` columns but would require a function-based index) then:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   table_name
WHERE  thedate > TO_NUMBER( TO_CHAR( SYSDATE - 5, 'YYYYMMDD' ) )
OR     (   thedate = TO_NUMBER( TO_CHAR( SYSDATE - 5, 'YYYYMMDD' ) )
       AND thetime >= TO_NUMBER( TO_CHAR( SYSDATE - 5, 'HH24MISS' ) )
       )
```

However, the better solution is to use appropriate data-types for your data; in this case, you should store date values in a `DATE` data-type (which, in Oracle, contains year-second components) rather than as two `INT` values for date and time.

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=eca7843d3d244f90cd1f4c32b3982ec5)*